# thread safe with pop and visit in c++ queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, thread-safety

I know std::queue is not thread safe, but I don't want to lock queue.
so I use pop & push limit on usages.

for instance, 
when I want to pop:
I have an enum to express first element status

```
enum {
    Busy = 1,
    Unused,
}
```

when I add an elment to queue:

```
void UserAdd() {
    lock.lock();
    element.status = BUSY;
    queue.push_back(element);
    lock.unlock();
}
```

when I visit :

```
//only visit function, and every element only called once.
void UserVisit() {
    auto header = queue.front();
    .......
    queue.front().status = UNUSED;
    return ;
}
```

I judge first elements status when I want to pop element.

If first element is Busy, wait;

If first element is Unused, pop;

```
void UserPop() {
    while (queue.front().status != Unused) {
        usleep(200);
    }
    lock.lock();
    queue.pop();
    lock.unlock();
}
```

thread A: 1. UserAdd, 2. UserVisit, 1.UserAdd, 2.UserVisit loop ...

thread B: 1. UserPop.

Is UserPop() && UserVisit thread safe ?.

I think It's thread safe.

Comment: Why do you think it is thread-safe?

Comment: No, you program is not thread-safe, because your "unused" test (and manipulation) are not atomic. you must **lock ()** semaphore ( or mutex or other synchronisation mechanism) at the begining of the function, and **release ()** semaphore (or mutex or critical_section or other synchronisation mechanisme) at the end of your function

Comment: Why even use the enum, when you then introduce a lock?

Comment: If pop function only connect with first element, I visit other element should be allowed.

Comment: There is no need to lock: `element.status = BUSY;` because element is not shared at this time with other threads

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I think too, but I afraid visit & pop don't locl is a undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

#### No thread safety

Note that the member function `pop()` does modify the queue. If `UserPop()` is called by multiple threads concurrently, one thread may modify the queue by calling `pop()` on it at the same time another thread is reading the queue by calling `front()`:

```
void UserPop() {
    while (queue.front().status != Unused) { // <-- read queue
        usleep(200);
    }
    queue.pop(); // <-- modify queue
}
```

Since the queue itself, `std::queue`, doesn't handle concurrent access for you, `UserPop()` is not thread-safe.

---

#### Make it thread safe

A simple approach to make it thread-safe is to add a mutex and hold a lock on it when reading or modifying the queue:

```
std::mutex mtx;

// ...

void UserPop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    // mtx is locked at this point
    while (queue.front().status != Unused) {
        lck.unlock();
        usleep(200); // mtx is not locked
        lck.lock();
    }
    // mtx is locked at this point
    queue.pop();
}
```

`std::queue`'s member functions `front()` and `pop()` above are always called while holding a lock on the mutex.

However, you may want to consider using [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) instead. It provides an optimization over the busy waiting:

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void UserPop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck, [this]() { return queue.front().status == Unused; });
    queue.pop();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207987/discussion-on-answer-by--thread-safe-with-pop-and-visit-in-c-queue).